# vendor/bin/phpunit exited with 2

Tags: phpunit, travis-ci, xdebug

I have a problem with PHPUnit on travis.ci. When I run my job in PHP 7.2 everything works; on the other hand tested with PHP 7.3 or 7.4 I get this error:

[image: error PHPUnit]

```yaml
language: php
php:
  - '7.2'
  - '7.3'
  - '7.4'
env:
  global:
    - CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
before_script:
  - curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
  - chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
  - ./cc-test-reporter before-build
script:
  - composer install
  - composer require symfony/phpunit-bridge:3.4.42
  - composer require symfony/http-foundation:3.4.42
  - composer require symfony/framework-bundle:3.4.42
  - composer require symfony/security-core:3.4.42
  - composer require symfony/console:3.4.42
  - composer require codeclimate/php-test-reporter
  - composer require symfony/serializer
  - composer require symfony/property-access
  - vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover=clover.xml
after_script:
  - ./cc-test-reporter after-build -t clover --exit-code $TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT
  - cp clover.xml coverage.xml
after_success:
  # Submit coverage report to https://codecov.io
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Here is the link of my job on Travis: https://travis-ci.com/github/viduc/casbundle

Thank you in advance for any help you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey we encounter the same issue and it seems that this is related to that issue https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1903

There was a fix that has been released but I think travis have to change the version of xDebug they are using.

We found a workaround by disabling xDebug when running tests via `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
```

See:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#disabling-preinstalled-php-extensions for details.